# Different ACCOUNT_STATUS for a Same User in Two Different Tables (Oracle DB)

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I’m studying for management of Oracle Database (Oracle 12C) nowadays,
and got a question while viewing two tables in the database I viewed.

There was a conflict on account_status of an account. The account_status of the account was “OPEN” in **v#pwfile_user** table, while it was “EXPIRED&LOCKED” in **dba_users** table.

Through googling, I got that tables named ‘v$~’ and tables named ‘dba_~’ run on different layer, but I cannot really understand how that exactly induces the account_status conflict I noticed.

I want to know **1) the reason** - how the conflict happened -, and **2) which account_status (between the on in the two tables) will be prioritized** in this situation.

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`v$pwfile_users` interrogates the password file on the host the instance is running on (created via `orapwd`) through a fixed table (`x$kzsrt`) and shows which authentication users have been set up with the ability to connect remotely as SYSDBA or other SYS-level identities. These entries are added upon `GRANT SYSDBA TO`, et al. It only governs the ability to connect remotely with these elevated privs. In most databases, it will be empty. It is rare that this view is used for anything.

`DBA_USERS` queries the `user$` dictionary table and displays database users created with `CREATE USER`, or that came preinstalled with every Oracle database. This is probably the only view you need to consider. The account status in this view is the one that matters.

It is actually not clear what the account status even means from `v$pwfile_users`, as this isn't coming the `user$` table but an OS file that does not contain this information according to any documentation I've ever seen, nor do I see how it could get updated when these attributes change. In fact this view didn't have this column (nor the date columns) prior to 12cR2. It simply had the username and the SYS identity granted. Perhaps Oracle is preparing for a future enhancement. It will be interesting to see if anyone knows why these additional columns showed up in 12cR2. Until then, I wouldn't pay it any mind. `DBA_USERS` is what you need.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing your knowledge! I really appreciate your detailed explanation about those two tables and even the possible implication of account_status field of v$pwfile_users table. It really helped!